# WordPress Blog post layout different to each other

Tags: php, css, wordpress, post, layout

I have stumbled across a problem, which makes both versions of the Blog different to each other when I'm not signed in to my site. Basically, I have built the site through WP. Once I've signed in the layout of the Blog Post is designed the way it is supposed to be like; completely laid out aesthetically and streamlined (image 1). 
[Blog Post Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoqOP.jpg)
However, I've checked the site afterwards to find that the layout has shifted the wrong way somewhat and that the blog text has blended into the footer, making things look undesirable (image 2).
[Blog Post Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM9Tk.jpg)
I have done everything in terms of deleting the cache and webpages just to refresh the whole site.

The code itself as I've double/triple-checked it again and again, but still no cigar.

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <header class="entry-header">
            <?php
            if ( is_singular() ) :
                the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
            else :
                the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
            endif;

            if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) :
                ?>


        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>

                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( array( 750, 750 )); ?>

                    <?php } ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

    <p class="article_date"><?php the_date(); ?></p>
                      <div class="blogTextExc">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                          Hello
                      </div>

            <?php edit_post_link( 'Edit', '<div>', '</div>'  ); ?>

    </article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

Please help!!!!

Comment: One thing is:  if `get_post_type()` does not return post, you are not closing your `<header>`

Comment: I've solved it! It was something more to do with the code. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You made some mistake in your code.
Header should be  closed before if statement ( 'post' === get_post_type() )
Your code should look like this:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php
        if ( is_singular() ) :
            the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
        else :
            the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
        endif; 
        ?>

    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <?php if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) :

          if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 

                the_post_thumbnail( array( 750, 750 ));

                } 
     endif; ?>

<p class="article_date"><?php the_date(); ?></p>
                  <div class="blogTextExc">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                      Hello
                  </div>

        <?php edit_post_link( 'Edit', '<div>', '</div>'  ); ?>

</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```